# pointer to pointer versus a pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I was experimenting with a double pointer(pointer to a pointer) and wanted to understand it properly . I was trying out the following code

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int y = 5;
    int *p = &y;
    int *q = &p;

    printf("\n\n %p %p %p %p %d\n\n",q,&p,p,*q,*p);

    return 0;

 }
```

Now in the above code , p is a pointer pointing to y and q is a pointer pointing to p. I have purposely not used a double pointer (**q) ,just to check what happens. The compiler gave me a warning indicating incompatible pointer type . When I executed the code ,I understood that q is a pointer to p ,so it contains the address of p ,but *q is not giving me the value contained in p ,that is the address of y ,rather I got some junk value. Is it because I have not declared q as a double pointer ? Can anyone explain why exactly I am getting some weird value for *q ?

Comment: q is **not** a pointer pointing to p

Comment: You are breaking the rules for q, hence the warning, but I admit I am not sure what should be printed in this example.  Probably a standards issue violation or something leading to undefined behavior?  I'll let someone else take a crack at this one.

Comment: @EugenRieck Where then does `q` point?

Comment: When you ask questions like this, which deliberately use code that violates the C standard, you must specify which C implementation you are using (compiler name, version, target platform, switches used to compile, et cetera). You should also show exactly what output you received. Obviously, there is no answer based on the C standard alone, but sometimes there are answers based on how your particular implementation works. But those answers cannot be given if you do not give the necessary information.

Answer (score 3):

> I got some junk value. Is it because I have not declared q as a double pointer ?

In essence, yes: since you declared `q` as a pointer to `int`, the dereference operation `*q` thinks that the address is an `int`. When that `int` is sent to `%p` as a pointer, you hit undefined behavior. Note that the behavior would remain undefined even on platforms where the representation of a pointer is exactly the same as than of an `int`. That's the treacherous nature of undefined behavior: sometimes it works "by mistake".

Comment: p, *q, and &y all point to the same address; q and &p point to the same address also

Comment: @0A0D Not as far as the compiler is concerned: to the compiler, `*q` does not "point" to anything, because it's an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `p` is a pointer to an int, which means the `&p` is a pointer to a pointer to int. Therefore, `q` should be declared as `int**`

From my comment below... you have declared `q` incorrectly... therefore, `*q` is an integer, not a pointer, and you are passing an integer into `printf()` where it is looking for a memory address... pretty much anything after that is undefined behavior.

Comment: He gets this, but was wondering why the value printed was junk.

Comment: Also the `*q` in the `printf()` would need to be `**q`.

Comment: Because of the answer I gave... `q` is declared incorrectly, therefore the compilation is treating `*q` as an `int`, not an `int*` which means that an integer, not a pointer to an integer is being passed to `printf`

Answer (score 1):

This line is not correct

```
 int *q = &p;
```

&p is the address of a pointer (p) which is pointing to an int (y)

assigning it to an pointer to an int (q) will make an reinterpretation

*q will interpret the address of p as an integer. That is not the same as the content of y (=5)

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone explain why exactly I am getting some weird value for `*q` ?

There are several problems:

- Firstly, by using `*q` you are trying to interpret a pointer as an `int`. This is not valid.
- Secondly, your `printf()` format specifier doesn't match the type of the fifth argument.

On some platforms (including the computer I am typing this on) a pointer is **wider** than an `int`. If I run your code on my computer, I get:

```
0x7fff5ef94ad8 0x7fff5ef94ad8 0x7fff5ef94ae4 0x5ef94ae4 5
```

Here, the 64-bit pointer is getting truncated to a 32-bit `int`. Therefore, only the lower part of the pointer is getting displayed. However, since the behaviour of your code is undefined it could well have failed in other ways.